# Sparql query on restriction list (Equivalent To) in protégé

Tags: sparql, owl, protege, rdfs, pellet

My ontology is about Cocktail. This is a cocktail named "AfterGlow"

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="&cocktails;AfterGlow">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&cocktails;aPourIngredient"/>
                    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&cocktails;JusAnanas"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&cocktails;aPourIngredient"/>
                    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&cocktails;JusOrange"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&cocktails;aPourIngredient"/>
                    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&cocktails;SiropGrenadine"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&cocktails;aPourDescription"/>
                    <owl:hasValue>Descriptoion AfterGlow</owl:hasValue>
                </owl:Restriction>
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&cocktails;aPourTitre"/>
                    <owl:hasValue>AfterGlow</owl:hasValue>
                </owl:Restriction>
            </owl:intersectionOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&cocktails;Cocktail"/>
</owl:Class>
```

`JusOrange` means Orange juice
`JusAnanas` means Pineapple juice

`aPourIngredient` is a `property` which means "has(contain) the ingredient"

[image]

This is the request which list all my cocktails with theirs rectrictions

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/cocktails#>
SELECT *
WHERE { 
  ?Cocktail rdfs:subClassOf :Cocktail.
  ?Cocktail owl:equivalentClass ?restriction .
}
```

[image]

**How can I request for example "select all cocktail which contains JusAnanas AND JusOrange"**

You can find my ontology here :

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ontologycero/cocktailsOnthology.owl
```

I've already found an ugly request, but it's not usable because we have to know the ontology for use this kind of request.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/cocktails#>
SELECT *
WHERE { 
  ?Cocktail rdfs:subClassOf :Cocktail.
  ?Cocktail owl:equivalentClass ?restriction .
  ?restriction owl:intersectionOf ?intersection.
  ?intersection rdf:first ?ingredient1.
  ?intersection rdf:rest ?rest1.
  ?rest1 rdf:first ?ingredient2.
  ?rest1 rdf:rest ?rest2.
  ?rest2 rdf:first ?ingredient3.

  ?ingredient1 owl:someValuesFrom :JusAnanas.
  ?ingredient2 owl:someValuesFrom :JusOrange.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are looking for, but as far as I understand you want to bypass the structure of the ontology. Since you don't know what comes after restriction, you can mention to the query to check wall the possible combinations.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/cocktails#>
SELECT *
WHERE { 
  ?Cocktail rdfs:subClassOf :Cocktail.
  ?Cocktail owl:equivalentClass ?restriction .
  ?restriction (rdfs:subClassOf|(owl:intersectionOf/rdf:rest*/rdf:first))* ?ingredient1.
  ?restriction (rdfs:subClassOf|(owl:intersectionOf/rdf:rest*/rdf:first))* ?ingredient2.
  ?ingredient1 owl:someValuesFrom :JusAnanas.
  ?ingredient2 owl:someValuesFrom :JusOrange.
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. Your request give me all the cocktails containing :JusAnanas OR :JusOrange. I need the cocktails which contain :JusAnanas AND :JusOrange

Comment: How about just adding another ingredient. It would be a bit nicer than yours, and I don't think your gives the right answer anyway. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

SPARQL isn't meant to understand the formal OWL model you've set up.  It's a graph pattern matching query language for RDF triples.  So instead of trying to query through the model, query the data using the semantics of the model you've designed:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
   ?coctails rdfs:subClassOf* :Cocktail .
   ?aoCocktail a ?coctails .
   ?aoCocktail :aPourIngredient :JusAnanas .
   ?aoCocktail :aPourIngredient :JusOrange .
}
```

The first two triple patterns find all member of `:Cocktail` and its subclasses.  The last two triple patterns find all members that have both `:JusOrange` and `:JusAnanas` as values for the property `:aPourIngredient`.