# Protege Equivalent to query

Tags: sparql, semantics, semantic-web, protege4

Please help to list all Mealcourse from the wine Ontology or happy to receive useful links like this one :[Sparql query on restriction list (Equivalent To) in protégé](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396707/sparql-query-on-restriction-list-equivalent-to-in-prot%C3%A9g%C3%A9)

MealCourse
and (hasFood value Pizza)
and(hasDrink value Wine)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit complicated, but if you look into the ontology everything that is defined as a `:MealCourse` is an `owl:equivalentClass`, so you need to first find all `owl:equivalentClass` and then if you look into the result you will see that they are made of `owl:intersectionOf` parts. Then you need to break this intersection and filter so that you will only get objects that have `:MealCourse` as part of the intersection.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/food#>
SELECT distinct *
    WHERE { ?subject owl:equivalentClass ?object. 
    ?object (owl:intersectionOf | owl:unionOf) ?node.
    ?node rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?eq.
    Filter ( ?eq in (:MealCourse ) )
}
orderBy ?subject
```