# ontology research EquivalentTo class from multiple single classes

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, owl, ontology

I'm playing with the Pizza ontology, and I'm trying to obtain what I understood as an inferred knowledge.
With some single classes, I would like to obtain the name of other classes using them.

To be exact, in the Pizza ontology we can find :

- Food
- Food/Pizza
- Food/Pizza/CheeseyPizza (Equivalent To `Pizza and (hasTopping some CheeseTopping)` ; SubClass Of `hasBase some PizzaBase`)
- Food/PizzaBase
- Food/PizzaBase/DeepPanBase
- Food/PizzaTopping
- Food/PizzaTopping/MozzarellaTopping

I'm trying to write a SPARQL request using `MozzarellaTopping` and `DeepPanBase` that may give me in the result `CheeseyPizza`... but I don't know how to do it, and I don't know if it's possible to do so.
(I read somewhere it was possible to do inferences on individuals, not on classes ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396707/sparql-query-on-restriction-list-equivalent-to-in-protégé](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396707/sparql-query-on-restriction-list-equivalent-to-in-prot%C3%A9g%C3%A9))... but Protégé seems to make inferences on the `CheeseyPizza`).

For now, I just got the common ancestors list (using Jena examples) :

```
showQuery(model, prefix
        + "SELECT ?o "
        + "WHERE { "
        + " pizza:MozzarellaTopping rdfs:subClassOf* ?o . "
        + " pizza:DeepPanBase rdfs:subClassOf* ?o . "
        + " FILTER ( ! isBlank(?o) ) " + "} "
        );
```

Is there a SPARQL request to obtain inferred classes, from single classes, without knowing the ontology structure ?
(Without knowing the ontology structure : in the ancestors request, I just put the two classes name, but I never gave the Food/Pizza structure... I really want to make a real research in the whole ontology with everything that requires Mozzarella and DeepPan)

Thank you !

**EDIT :**

I forget to say that I was also thinking of using a reasoner (I'm working on Jena).
But I don't know if that's the correct way of making it.

Comment: For your case you would need OWL RL as entailment regime which has to be implemented by the SPARQL engine then. In Jena you can use an `OntModel`, documentation on how to use inference is here: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a lot of documentation, and I think I finally found the solution.
It's not exactly what I expected, but for now it will be enough.
The main idea : create individuals (which are instances of concepts/classes), link them together, and ask a reasoner to discover things (inferences).

Useful docs (thank you StakOverflow for the links) :

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#owl

http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/#instances-or-individuals

http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/index.html

First, what is my solution :

- instantiate the base model (and load the pizza ontology)
- instantiate an inference model (and choose a reasoner)
- create in the base model : multiple individuals and properties/relations between them
- check validity of model, ask for assertion (in base model) and

It's working. I can create an individual "MozzarellaTopping", an individual "DeepPanBase", and an individual "Food". I added two properties to "Food" : hasBase to individual DeepPanBase, and hasTopping to individual MozzarellaTopping.

Here is the code explained step by step (full code at the end) :

Instantiate and Load base model from pizza.owl.rdf

```
    public static final String  SOURCE      = "./resources/";
    public static final String  PIZZA_NS    = "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#";

    public void run()
    {
        // Prefix/Header for SPARQL requests
        final String prefix = "prefix pizza: <" + PIZZA_NS + ">\n"
                + "prefix rdfs: <" + RDFS.getURI() + ">\n" + "prefix owl: <"
                + OWL.getURI() + ">\n";
        // Prefix for classes, individuals, ... for every object
        final String NS = PIZZA_NS;

        System.out.println("CREATE THE BASE MODEL\n");
        // CREATE THE BASE MODEL
        OntModel base = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
        base.read(SOURCE + "pizza.owl.rdf", "RDF/XML");
```

Create the inferred model :

```
    System.out.println("CREATE THE REASONING MODEL USING THE BASE\n");
        // CREATE THE REASONING MODEL USING THE BASE
        OntModel inf = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF, base);
        // OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF // It works + Very quick
        // OWL_MEM_MINI_RULE_INF // It works + Slow (40Mins) + 1,1Go RAM (Validity is slow)
        // OWL_MEM_RULE_INF // It works (mights loop if error) + VERY SLOW + 2,1 GO RAM (unfinished)
        // OWL_MEM_TRANS_INF // It works (SPARQL mights not work) + Ultra Speed / No inference
```

Get useful Classes and Properties in java for future individuals instantiation :

```
        System.out.println("CREATE INDIVIDUALS FOR TESTING PURPOSE\n");
        // CREATE INDIVIDUALS FOR TESTING PURPOSE

        // Instantiate each useful Class
        OntClass ThingClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "owl:Thing");
        OntClass FoodClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "Food");
        OntClass IceCreamClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "IceCream");
        OntClass PizzaClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "Pizza");
        OntClass MozzaToppingClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "MozzarellaTopping");
        OntClass DeepPanBaseClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "DeepPanBase");

        // Instantiate each useful Property (relation)
        OntProperty hasIngredientProperty = base.createObjectProperty(NS + "hasIngredient");
        OntProperty hasBaseProperty = base.createObjectProperty(NS + "hasBase");
        OntProperty hasToppingProperty = base.createObjectProperty(NS + "hasTopping");

        // Instantiate each useful individual
        Individual MozzaTopping = base.createIndividual(NS + "MyMozzaTopping", MozzaToppingClass);
        Individual DeepPanBase = base.createIndividual(NS + "MyDeepPanBase", DeepPanBaseClass);
```

Then, I first check an individual with two simultaneous classes (MozzarellaTopping and DeepPanBase)... the reasoner see a CheeseyPizza, but the validity report doesn't work :

```
        /*
         * BEGINNING OF THE TESTS HERE
         */
        System.out.println("\nTEST VALIDITY BEFORE ADDING INDIVIDUALS\n");
        checkValidity(inf);

        // Instantiate testing individuals
        // MyPizza1 : individual with 2 classes simultaneously (Mozza & DeepPan)
        Individual MyPizza1 = base.createIndividual(NS + "MyPizza1", ThingClass);
        MyPizza1.setOntClass(MozzaToppingClass);
        MyPizza1.addOntClass(DeepPanBaseClass);

        System.out.println("\nTest MyPizza1\n");
        showAsserted(base, NS + "MyPizza1");
        showInferred(inf, NS + "MyPizza1");
        System.out.println("\nTest Validity of MyPizza1 : ");
        checkValidity(inf); // ERROR

        MyPizza1.remove();
        System.out.println("\nRemove MyPizza1, Validity should be OK now : ");
        checkValidity(inf); // OK
```

Then, I tried a "Food" (or "Pizza") individual to which I had a relation hasBase DeepPanBase, and another relation hasTopping MozzarellaTopping. It's working, ni problem in validity check :

```
        // MyPizza2 : individual of class "Food", linked with Mozza & DeepPan
        Individual MyPizza2 = base.createIndividual(NS + "MyPizza2", FoodClass);
        MyPizza2.addProperty(hasBaseProperty, DeepPanBase);
        MyPizza2.addProperty(hasToppingProperty, MozzaTopping);

        System.out.println("\nTest MyPizza2\n");
        showAsserted(base, NS + "MyPizza2");
        showInferred(inf, NS + "MyPizza2");
        System.out.println("\nTest Validity of MyPizza2 : ");
        checkValidity(inf); // OK

        MyPizza2.remove();
        System.out.println("\nRemove MyPizza2, Validity should be OK now : ");
        checkValidity(inf); // OK
```

Then, I try a DeepPanBase individual, to which I give a property/relation hasTopping MozzarellaTopping. The reasoner also acts as you might think : he says it's a CheeseyPizza, but, the validity check says it's wrong.

```
        // MyPizza3 : individual of class "DeepPanBase", linked with Mozza
        Individual MyPizza3 = base.createIndividual(NS + "MyPizza3", DeepPanBaseClass);
        MyPizza3.addProperty(hasToppingProperty, MozzaTopping);

        System.out.println("\nTest MyPizza3\n");
        showAsserted(base, NS + "MyPizza3");
        showInferred(inf, NS + "MyPizza3");
        System.out.println("\nTest Validity of MyPizza3 : ");
        checkValidity(inf); // ERROR

        MyPizza3.remove();
        System.out.println("\nRemove MyPizza3, Validity should be OK now : ");
        checkValidity(inf); // OK
```

Finally, a test with an IceCream individual (Food) is made. I give it a relation hasBase DeepPanBase and another relation hasTopping MozzarellaTopping. The reasoner says it's a CheeseyPizza, and the validity check shout that it's wrong.

```
        // IceCream : individual of class "IceCream", linked with Moza & DeePan
        Individual MyIceCream = base.createIndividual(NS + "MyIceCream", IceCreamClass);
        MyIceCream.addProperty(hasBaseProperty, DeepPanBase);
        MyIceCream.addProperty(hasToppingProperty, MozzaTopping);

        System.out.println("\nTest IceCream\n");
        showAsserted(base, NS + "MyIceCream");
        showInferred(inf, NS + "MyIceCream");
        System.out.println("\nTest Validity of IceCream : ");
        checkValidity(inf);
```

The validity checker is right. If you check what is a Pizza, you'll see it's an individual "Food" which contains "ingredients"/toppings, and at least one PizzaBase... but it's also something that is NOT a PizzaTopping, NOT a PizzaBase, and NOT an IceCream. (this is why the validity check is crying... if I try to put PizzaTopping on an IceCream, it's impossible...)

---

Anyway, As promised I give the full code here :

```
    /*
     * Example of usage of reasoner with Java. Everything is coming from Apache JENA
     * examples. I modified a lot of things for making my personal requests.
     * Fabrice Boissier
     */

    package Jena_Reasoner_Simple;

    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Iterator;

    import org.apache.jena.ontology.Individual;
    import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntClass;
    import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModel;
    import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
    import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntProperty;
    import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
    import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
    import org.apache.jena.reasoner.ValidityReport;
    import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.OWL;
    import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.RDFS;

    public class Simple_Reasoner_StepByStep
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("BEGIN : " + new Date());
        new Simple_Reasoner_StepByStep().run();
        System.out.println("END : " + new Date());
    }

    public static final String  SOURCE      = "./resources/";
    public static final String  PIZZA_NS    = "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#";

    public void run()
    {
        // Prefix/Header for SPARQL requests
        final String prefix = "prefix pizza: <" + PIZZA_NS + ">\n"
                + "prefix rdfs: <" + RDFS.getURI() + ">\n" + "prefix owl: <"
                + OWL.getURI() + ">\n";
        // Prefix for classes, individuals, ... for every object
        final String NS = PIZZA_NS;

        System.out.println("CREATE THE BASE MODEL\n");
        // CREATE THE BASE MODEL
        OntModel base = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
        base.read(SOURCE + "pizza.owl.rdf", "RDF/XML");

        System.out.println("CREATE THE REASONING MODEL USING THE BASE\n");
        // CREATE THE REASONING MODEL USING THE BASE
        OntModel inf = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF, base);
        // OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF // It works + Very quick
        // OWL_MEM_MINI_RULE_INF // It works + Slow (40Mins) + 1,1Go RAM (Validity is slow)
        // OWL_MEM_RULE_INF // It works (mights loop if error) + VERY SLOW + 2,1 GO RAM (unfinished)
        // OWL_MEM_TRANS_INF // It works (SPARQL mights not work) + Ultra Speed / No inference

        System.out.println("CREATE INDIVIDUALS FOR TESTING PURPOSE\n");
        // CREATE INDIVIDUALS FOR TESTING PURPOSE

        // Instantiate each useful Class
        OntClass ThingClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "owl:Thing");
        OntClass FoodClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "Food");
        OntClass IceCreamClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "IceCream");
        OntClass PizzaClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "Pizza");
        OntClass MozzaToppingClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "MozzarellaTopping");
        OntClass DeepPanBaseClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "DeepPanBase");

        // Instantiate each useful Property (relation)
        OntProperty hasIngredientProperty = base.createObjectProperty(NS + "hasIngredient");
        OntProperty hasBaseProperty = base.createObjectProperty(NS + "hasBase");
        OntProperty hasToppingProperty = base.createObjectProperty(NS + "hasTopping");

        // Instantiate each useful individual
        Individual MozzaTopping = base.createIndividual(NS + "MyMozzaTopping", MozzaToppingClass);
        Individual DeepPanBase = base.createIndividual(NS + "MyDeepPanBase", DeepPanBaseClass);

        /*
         * BEGINNING OF THE TESTS HERE
         */
        System.out.println("\nTEST VALIDITY BEFORE ADDING INDIVIDUALS\n");
        checkValidity(inf);

        // Instantiate testing individuals
        // MyPizza1 : individual with 2 classes simultaneously (Mozza & DeepPan)
        Individual MyPizza1 = base.createIndividual(NS + "MyPizza1", ThingClass);
        MyPizza1.setOntClass(MozzaToppingClass);
        MyPizza1.addOntClass(DeepPanBaseClass);

        System.out.println("\nTest MyPizza1\n");
        showAsserted(base, NS + "MyPizza1");
        showInferred(inf, NS + "MyPizza1");
        System.out.println("\nTest Validity of MyPizza1 : ");
        checkValidity(inf); // ERROR

        MyPizza1.remove();
        System.out.println("\nRemove MyPizza1, Validity should be OK now : ");
        checkValidity(inf); // OK

        // MyPizza2 : individual of class "Food", linked with Mozza & DeepPan
        Individual MyPizza2 = base.createIndividual(NS + "MyPizza2", FoodClass);
        MyPizza2.addProperty(hasBaseProperty, DeepPanBase);
        MyPizza2.addProperty(hasToppingProperty, MozzaTopping);

        System.out.println("\nTest MyPizza2\n");
        showAsserted(base, NS + "MyPizza2");
        showInferred(inf, NS + "MyPizza2");
        System.out.println("\nTest Validity of MyPizza2 : ");
        checkValidity(inf); // OK

        MyPizza2.remove();
        System.out.println("\nRemove MyPizza2, Validity should be OK now : ");
        checkValidity(inf); // OK

        // MyPizza3 : individual of class "DeepPanBase", linked with Mozza
        Individual MyPizza3 = base.createIndividual(NS + "MyPizza3", DeepPanBaseClass);
        MyPizza3.addProperty(hasToppingProperty, MozzaTopping);

        System.out.println("\nTest MyPizza3\n");
        showAsserted(base, NS + "MyPizza3");
        showInferred(inf, NS + "MyPizza3");
        System.out.println("\nTest Validity of MyPizza3 : ");
        checkValidity(inf); // ERROR

        MyPizza3.remove();
        System.out.println("\nRemove MyPizza3, Validity should be OK now : ");
        checkValidity(inf); // OK

        // IceCream : individual of class "IceCream", linked with Moza & DeePan
        Individual MyIceCream = base.createIndividual(NS + "MyIceCream", IceCreamClass);
        MyIceCream.addProperty(hasBaseProperty, DeepPanBase);
        MyIceCream.addProperty(hasToppingProperty, MozzaTopping);

        System.out.println("\nTest IceCream\n");
        showAsserted(base, NS + "MyIceCream");
        showInferred(inf, NS + "MyIceCream");
        System.out.println("\nTest Validity of IceCream : ");
        checkValidity(inf);

        /*
         * END OF THE TESTS HERE
         */

        System.out.println("End Tests\n");
    }

    protected void showAsserted(OntModel m, String individualURI)
    {
        // list the asserted types
        Individual instance = m.getIndividual(individualURI); // BASE
        for (Iterator<Resource> i = instance.listRDFTypes(false); i.hasNext();)
        {
            System.out
                    .println(instance.getURI() + " is asserted in class " + i.next());
        }
    }

    protected void showInferred(OntModel m, String individualURI)
    {
        // list the inferred types
        Individual instance = m.getIndividual(individualURI); // INFERED
        for (Iterator<Resource> i = instance.listRDFTypes(false); i.hasNext();)
        {
            System.out.println(
                    instance.getURI() + " is inferred to be in class " + i.next());
        }
    }

    protected void checkValidity(OntModel inf)
    {
        ValidityReport validity = inf.validate();
        if (validity.isValid())
        {
            System.out.println("OK");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Conflicts");
            for (Iterator i = validity.getReports(); i.hasNext();)
            {
                System.out.println(" - " + i.next());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

To make the code runs on Eclipse or other, you'll need first to put the pizza ontologie file (pizza.owl.rdf) in a folder named "resources", and add these JAR (in Eclipse : Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Add JARs) :

- commons-cli-1.3.jar
- commons-lang3-3.4.jar
- httpclient-4.5.2.jar
- httpclient-cache-4.5.2.jar
- httpcore-4.4.4.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar
- jackson-core-2.7.4.jar
- jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar
- jena-arq-3.3.0.jar
- jena-base-3.3.0.jar
- jena-core-3.3.0.jar
- jena-iri-3.3.0.jar
- jena-rdfconnection-3.3.0.jar
- jena-shaded-guava-3.3.0.jar
- jsonld-java-0.9.0.jar
- libthrift-0.9.3.jar
- log4j-1.2.17.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar
- xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
- xml-apis-1.4.01.jar

Answer (score 2):

In order to upgrade the answer, here is a small code for loading a model with Jena, launch a reasonner on it, add individuals (which create inferences), and make multiple SPARQL requests on the base model and the infered model to get individuals following there class :

```
package Jena_Reasoner_SPARQL;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.jena.ontology.Individual;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntProperty;
import org.apache.jena.query.Query;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import org.apache.jena.reasoner.ValidityReport;
import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.OWL;
import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.RDFS;

public class Simple_Reasoner_and_SPARQL_Request
{
    public static final String  SOURCE      = "./resources/";
    public static final String  PIZZA_NS    = "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#";
    public static final String  prefix      = "prefix pizza: <" + PIZZA_NS + ">\n"
                                            + "prefix rdfs: <" + RDFS.getURI() + ">\n"
                                            + "prefix owl: <" + OWL.getURI() + ">\n";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("BEGIN " + new Date());

        new Simple_Reasoner_and_SPARQL_Request().run();

        System.out.println("END " + new Date());
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String NS = PIZZA_NS;

        System.out.println("CREATE AND LOAD THE BASE MODEL");
        // CREATE AND LOAD THE BASE MODEL
        OntModel base = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
        base.read(SOURCE + "pizza.owl.rdf", "RDF/XML");

        System.out.println("CREATE THE REASONING MODEL USING THE BASE\n");
        // CREATE THE REASONING MODEL USING THE BASE
        OntModel inf = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF, base);
        // OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF // It works + Very quick
        // OWL_MEM_MINI_RULE_INF // It works + Slow (40Mins) + 1,1Go RAM (Validity is slow)
        // OWL_MEM_RULE_INF // It works (mights loop if error) + VERY SLOW + 2,1Go RAM (unfinished)
        // OWL_MEM_TRANS_INF // It works (SPARQL mights not work) + Ultra Speed / No inference

        System.out.println("CREATE INDIVIDUALS FOR TESTING PURPOSE\n");
        // CREATE INDIVIDUALS FOR TESTING PURPOSE

        // Instantiate each useful Class
        OntClass ThingClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "owl:Thing");
        OntClass FoodClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "Food");
        OntClass IceCreamClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "IceCream");
        OntClass PizzaClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "Pizza");
        OntClass MozzaToppingClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "MozzarellaTopping");
        OntClass DeepPanBaseClass = base.getOntClass(NS + "DeepPanBase");

        // Instantiate each useful Property (relation)
        OntProperty hasIngredientProperty = base.createObjectProperty(NS + "hasIngredient");
        OntProperty hasBaseProperty = base.createObjectProperty(NS + "hasBase");
        OntProperty hasToppingProperty = base.createObjectProperty(NS + "hasTopping");

        // Instantiate each useful individual
        Individual MozzaTopping = base.createIndividual(NS + "MyMozzaTopping", MozzaToppingClass);
        Individual DeepPanBase = base.createIndividual(NS + "MyDeepPanBase", DeepPanBaseClass);

        /*
         * BEGINNING OF THE TESTS HERE
         */
        System.out.println("\nTEST VALIDITY BEFORE ADDING INDIVIDUALS " + new Date() + "\n");
        checkValidity(inf);

        // Instantiate testing individuals
        // MyPizza1 : individual of class "Food", linked with Mozza & DeepPan
        Individual MyPizza1 = base.createIndividual(NS + "MyPizza1", FoodClass);
        MyPizza1.addProperty(hasBaseProperty, DeepPanBase);
        MyPizza1.addProperty(hasToppingProperty, MozzaTopping);

        System.out.println("\nTest MyPizza1 " + new Date() + "\n");
        showAsserted(base, NS + "MyPizza1");
        showInferred(inf, NS + "MyPizza1");
        System.out.println("\nTest Validity of MyPizza1 : " + new Date());
        checkValidity(inf); // OK

        // SPARQL Tests now
        System.out.println("\nSPARQL TESTS\n");
        printPrefix();

        // Research every Food
        System.out.println("\nResearch Food in Base model");
        showQuery(base,
                prefix + "SELECT ?individual " + "WHERE { "
                        + " ?individual a pizza:Food . "
                        + " FILTER ( ! isBlank(?individual) ) " + "} ");

        System.out.println("\nResearch Food in Inference model");
        showQuery(inf,
                prefix + "SELECT ?individual " + "WHERE { "
                        + " ?individual a pizza:Food . "
                        + " FILTER ( ! isBlank(?individual) ) " + "} ");

        // Research every CheeseyPizza
        System.out.println("\nResearch CheeseyPizza in Base model");
        showQuery(base,
                prefix + "SELECT ?individual " + "WHERE { "
                        + " ?individual a pizza:CheeseyPizza . "
                        + " FILTER ( ! isBlank(?individual) ) " + "} ");

        System.out.println("\nResearch CheeseyPizza in Inference model");
        showQuery(inf,
                prefix + "SELECT ?individual " + "WHERE { "
                        + " ?individual a pizza:CheeseyPizza . "
                        + " FILTER ( ! isBlank(?individual) ) " + "} ");

        /*
         * END OF THE TESTS HERE
         */

        System.out.println("End Tests\n");
    }

    protected void showAsserted(OntModel m, String individualURI)
    {
        // list the asserted types
        Individual instance = m.getIndividual(individualURI); // BASE
        for (Iterator<Resource> i = instance.listRDFTypes(false); i.hasNext();)
        {
            System.out
                    .println(instance.getURI() + " is asserted in class " + i.next());
        }
    }

    protected void showInferred(OntModel m, String individualURI)
    {
        // list the inferred types
        Individual instance = m.getIndividual(individualURI); // INFERED
        for (Iterator<Resource> i = instance.listRDFTypes(false); i.hasNext();)
        {
            System.out.println(
                    instance.getURI() + " is inferred to be in class " + i.next());
        }
    }

    protected void checkValidity(OntModel inf)
    {
        ValidityReport validity = inf.validate();
        if (validity.isValid())
        {
            System.out.println("OK");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Conflicts");
            for (Iterator i = validity.getReports(); i.hasNext();)
            {
                System.out.println(" - " + i.next());
            }
        }
    }

    protected void printPrefix()
    {
        System.out.println(prefix);
    }

    protected void showQuery(Model m, String q)
    {
        Query query = QueryFactory.create(q);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, m);
        try
        {
            ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
            ResultSetFormatter.out(results, m);
        }
        finally
        {
            qexec.close();
        }

    }
}
```