# SPARQL query on restriction list

Tags: sparql, restriction, snomed-ct

I'm learning SPARQL and need some advices about a query.

**Exemple of the ontology :**

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://snomed.info/id/187903000">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://snomed.info/id/187900002"/>
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://snomed.info/id/609096000"/>
                    <owl:someValuesFrom>
                        <owl:Class>
                            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                                <owl:Restriction>
                                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://snomed.info/id/116676008"/>
                                    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://snomed.info/id/367651003"/>
                                </owl:Restriction>
                                <owl:Restriction>
                                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://snomed.info/id/363698007"/>
                                    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://snomed.info/id/13881006"/>
                                </owl:Restriction>
                            </owl:intersectionOf>
                        </owl:Class>
                    </owl:someValuesFrom>
                </owl:Restriction>
            </owl:intersectionOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://snomed.info/id/126546006"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://snomed.info/id/363501002"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://snomed.info/id/448558006"/>
    <field:Description.term.en-us.preferred xml:lang="en">Malignant neoplasm of malar bone</field:Description.term.en-us.preferred>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Malignant neoplasm of malar bone (disorder)</rdfs:label>
</owl:Class>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the URI present in **owl:someValuesFrom** depending of which URI present in **owl:onProperty**.

I tried this query :

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?subject ?fsn ?rs WHERE {
  ?subject rdfs:label ?fsn ;
  <http://snomed.info/id/116676008> ?rs .
}
```

following the advice of this post [Sparql query on restriction list (Equivalent To) in protégé](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396707/sparql-query-on-restriction-list-equivalent-to-in-prot%C3%A9g%C3%A9). But the 2 answers given in this post didn't work.

Have you got any ideas of what's wrong with my query ?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: I don't see how your query does follow the first query of the answer you linked to? I mean, SPARQL is graph pattern matching on RDF data, thus your query must reflect the path in your data or not?

Comment: The path is - beginning from the class - `?cls owl:equivalentClass ?restriction .
  ?restriction owl:intersectionOf/rdf:rest*/rdf:first ... ` - and even more complicated, your class expression is deeply nested: `A EquivalentTo (B1 and p1 some ((p2 some B2) and (p3 some B3)))` - you'll at least need this property path `(owl:intersectionOf/rdf:rest*/rdf:first)*` to handle nested intersections.

Comment: As a hint, look at your data in Turtle syntax, this is the syntax which SPARQL query patterns are basically do follow

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Concerning my link I spoked about the third and last answer. I'll check the Turtle syntax and your hint about path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people which may have the same question, the answer of AKSW is really helpfull and worked !

So I use the Turtle format to represent my ontology :

```
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix ns0: <http://snomed.info/field/Description.term.en-us.> .

<http://snomed.info/id/187903000>
  a owl:Class ;
  owl:equivalentClass [
    a owl:Class ;
    owl:intersectionOf (
      <http://snomed.info/id/187900002>
      _:genid3
    )
  ] ;
  rdfs:subClassOf <http://snomed.info/id/126546006>, <http://snomed.info/id/363501002>, <http://snomed.info/id/448558006> ;
  ns0:preferred "Malignant neoplasm of malar bone"@en ;
  rdfs:label "Malignant neoplasm of malar bone (disorder)"@en .

_:genid3
  a owl:Restriction ;
  owl:onProperty <http://snomed.info/id/609096000> ;
  owl:someValuesFrom [
    a owl:Class ;
    owl:intersectionOf (
      _:genid6
      _:genid8
    )
  ] .

_:genid6
  a owl:Restriction ;
  owl:onProperty <http://snomed.info/id/116676008> ;
  owl:someValuesFrom <http://snomed.info/id/367651003> .

_:genid8
  a owl:Restriction ;
  owl:onProperty <http://snomed.info/id/363698007> ;
  owl:someValuesFrom <http://snomed.info/id/13881006> .
```

With this format the way to query appear simplier. So if I want to retrieve the value of the property **http://snomed.info/id/363698007** I need to use the following query :

```
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT ?subject ?x WHERE {
  ?subject owl:equivalentClass/(owl:intersectionOf/rdf:rest+/rdf:first)*/owl:someValuesFrom/(owl:intersectionOf/rdf:rest*/rdf:first)* ?rs .
  ?rs owl:onProperty <http://snomed.info/id/363698007> ;
      owl:someValuesFrom ?x .
}
```

This query will give you the following result :

> ?subject : http://snomed.info/id/187903000
>   ?x : http://snomed.info/id/13881006

Comment: So paste full query with some explanation here, then accept your answer.